# how to update User record when profile.name is 'system admin'

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to update the user record (a text field) when user.profile.name =='system administrator' based on profile the permission set will add.
my issue is while updating its not taking the profile name

```
    public static void update(Map<id,user> oldMap,List<user> userList)
{
    for(user u :userList)   
    {
        if(oldMap!= null && u.User_Program_Configuration__c != oldMap.get(u.id).User_Program_Configuration__c)
        {
            
            
            Program__c proglist = new Program__c();
            List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissionSetList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
            
            string rname;
            list <string> progid = new list<string>();
            for(String opt: groupNames)
            {
                progid =opt.split('-');
               
                proglist =[Select id , name from Program__c where OPT_Program_ID__c in:progid limit 1];
                
                if (u.Profile.Name == 'System administrator')
                {
                    
                    rname = 'example '+proglist.name.replace(' ','_');
                    
                }
                
                    List<PermissionSet> pre =[SELECT Id, Name, Label FROM PermissionSet where label=:rname ];
                    
                    for(PermissionSet pset: pre)
                    {
                        PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = pset.id, AssigneeId = u.Id);
                        permissionSetList.add(psa);
                    }
                  try
    {
        upsert permissionSetList;
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        system.debug(e);
    }
```

}

Comment: you can save the Profile.Id for the `System Administrator` in custom metadata or custom label as the value will be invariant across all orgs - then compare `u.ProfileId` against that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is being called from a trigger, only the immediate fields of `User` will be populated. You will need to find the Id of the "System Administrator" Profile before the loop and match that with the `User.ProfileId` field in the loop.